# Iterate through Dictionary and create multiple subplots

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys that correspond to a given sensor, and within each entry, columns that correspond to sensor parameters(time, concentration, avg current).

What I have so far:
-A function that reads a text file and outputs a Pandas DF, with AVG calculations for each row along axis =1 (i.e. for each row, calculate the average across 8 sensor columns)

-A function that will create a dictionary of dataframes. The output looks like {'sensor name': time, sensor AVG, concentration}
def create_analysis_dict(path):

```
ddict = {}
global analysisdict
analysisdict = {}

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        print(name)
        ddict[name] = import_CHI_file(os.path.join(path, file))
        analysisdict[name] =df_analytics(ddict[name])
return analysisdict
```

What is the best way to iterate through the dictionary to generate multiple subplots of concentration (x-axis) vs avg current?

Comment: So what did u try so far?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have columns; python (without some external library) doesn't make plots.

Comment: @user1767754 sorry for the poor context, I updated the description